# safely ssh to web app users server

Tags: php, laravel, security, ssh

I am creating a Saas app that will need to ssh to a users remote host.  They will add there host and I will give them a public key to add to there authorized_keys.  My script would then be able to ssh to there host using key pair authenticatoin and run some commands.

My question is weather this is safe?  Is there any way they could reverse that and access my server?  Are there any precautions I would need to take?

The web app is using Laravel, but the ssh commands will be run by a Job.

Comment: Really is too broad for SO.  This is more of a theory question since you didn't provide specifics.  In theory, this won't be dangerous for you, it'd be dangerous for the end user depending on the level of access your public key would have over their server.  Having a public key wouldn't provide them with any details or power over your server.

Comment: No its one way, though If you get hacked you will have big problems other then being hacked. but it is the standard way, many do it. cloud9, deployhq for example.